# How do I stop Auto Outline Expansion in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatting

How to do I stop Visual Studio 2010 from expanding outlines/regions automatically?

Right now whenever I create certain syntax errors (usually while editing, sometimes just from starting to type new code), it will auto expand every outline/region below that line.

I've been through the formating settings, but I can't find anything. Maybe I don't know the proper terminology that applies to the setting.

Example code that causes this behavior(one of many):

```
public string myMethod1(string myStr)
{
    try //<-SELECT AND DELETE ME 
    {   //<-AND ME TOO, AT THE SAME TIME

        return myStr + "success"; 
    }
    catch
    {
        return myStr + "failed"; 
    }
}

//ALL OF THESE BELOW WERE COLLAPSED, 
//BUT WILL EXPAND WHEN "TRY {" IS DELETED
#region HIDING
public string myMethod2(string myStr) { /*...*/ }
public string myMethod3(string myStr) { /*...*/ }
public string myMethod4(string myStr) { /*...*/ }
public string myMethod5(string myStr) { /*...*/ }
#endregion HIDING
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**
I can force to happen by removing any starting bracket `{`, anywhere in my code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on VS 2010 SP 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal behavior. It is possible that an add-on you have installed is incorrectly doing this. You can reset your environment to the default settings by going to
Tools -> Import and Export Settings ...

- choose Reset all settings
- click next
- save your current settings if you want to
- then choose the default setting (I prefer General Development Settings because I work on lots of different things)
- Click finish

Saving your current settings allows you to keep your old stuff in case you do not like what defaults you have chosen. So there is really no chance for loss of your environment setup when you do this.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. I did it twice and restarted vs. Still does it.

Comment: If you have any add-ons installed, I would try removing them one at a time until you figure out which one is causing the problem. If that doesn't fix it, then it most likely is a bug specific to your system and setup

Comment: I may redownload it and try a fresh install. I don't have any add-ons. I also checked for updates, but I have none. I'm running Win 7 64bit.. I'm tempted to blame that.. but I haven't had very many 32 to 64 bit problems with Win 7. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I am running win 7 64bit as well, on two different machines, and I have never seen this problem.

Comment: I guess it's not that.. I just completely reinstalled it and still does it.. Oh well..

Comment: I'm running Win 7 64bit and VS 2010 Too and I can't reproduce your bug. This reminds of the behavior when you have a comment block `/* ... */`and you delete the second`*/`. Are you really sure this is the only line you delete, as is ???

Comment: Yes, I've replayed it several times. It always happens when I delete `try {`. I will also happen if I delete any starting `{`. Ending brackets `}` don't do it. I just did some more verification testing. It will do it if I delete any starting bracket `{`, anywhere in my code. It's very very very annoying. There's other ways to get it to happen, I just can't remember any of them right now.